# jquery sdocml not working in aptana studio 3 for eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, aptana, code-hinting

I first installed the Ruble and it didn't work. Then I read the instructions and place the jquery sdocml file in my project but it still didn't work. Even after restarting eclipse and making a new javascript file, I still get no code hinting. I have tried both 1.4.2 and 1.6.2 sdocml files.

Answer (score 1):

i had also problems to get code hinting to work. In my case it was the sdocml file for dojo. After trying with existing and new projects I recognized that "Build Project" has to be invoked before code hinting works.

HTH, Philipp